# Need help in understanding an argument.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Suppose $u: A\times B\to (0,\infty)$ be a function such that
$$
\int_{x\in A}\int_{y\in B}u^2(x,t)\,dx dt\leq \int_{x\in A}\int_{y\in B}f(u(x,t))\,dx dt.
$$
Now let us fix $\hat{t}\in B$, and define $v(x,\hat{t})=u(x,\hat{t})$, then is it possible to get
$$
\int_{x\in A}\int_{B}v^2(x,\hat{t})\,dx dt\leq \int_{x\in A}\int_{B}f(v(x,\hat{t}))\,dx dt.
$$

Note that is this holds then we get
$$
\int_{x\in A}u^2(x,\hat{t})\,dx\leq\int_{x\in A}f(u(x,\hat{t}))\,dx.
$$

You can take any function $f$. Basically, my question is if one can get the second one from the fist when one fixes the variable $t$ and get the same estimate for the one variable function $v(x,\hat{t})$?

Can somebody kindly help me?

Thanking you.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Also, I have added a consequence at the end if the result holds. Kindly look. Moreover, I have fixed $t$ at the point $\hat{t}$. So $u=v$ become a function of $x$ only.

Comment: It's quite unclear why we would do that... Consider $u(x,t)=t$ and $\hat t = \inf B$ to see what happens